# Sobrecarga em loop com uso de foreach

Tags: php, mysqli, loop, foreach

Ola estou tendo um grave problema pelo menos e o que a empresa de hospedagem aqual esta meu site fica alegando que o meu código abaixo esta sobrecarregando as consultas ou seja realizando vários loops, e não sei mais o que eu posso fazer.

Existe alguma forma de unificar ou aprimorar esse código para funcionar de forma mais efetiva ?

**Funcionamento do codigo:** O código literalmente faz isso primeiro faz aparecer as news e dentro de cada news você tem como fazer aparecer quantos itens você desejar na segunda consulta desde que o resultado da primeira consulta da tabela news coluna `medias` os valores separados por vigulas que no caso funcionam como ID's existam na tabela `medias` coluna `id` ele ira aplicar esses resultados dentro do `where in` fazendo aparecer dentro do segundo loop os itens na segunda consulta.

Segue abaixo as **SQL's** e os **códigos** juntamente com algumas explicações nele.

**SQL NEWS**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `titulo` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `noticia` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `hora` time NOT NULL,
  `medias` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `episodios` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `autor` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tituloUnico` (`titulo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `urlUnica` (`titulo_url`),
  KEY `news_indexada` (`id`,`titulo_url`,`autor`,`data`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**SQL Membros**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `membros` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `autor` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `senha` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'admin',
  `idade` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'exemplo@email.com',
  `cargo` enum('Adminstrador','Editor','Upload') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Adminstrador',
  `adm1` enum('ativado','desativado') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ativado',
  `adm2` enum('ativado','desativado') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ativado',
  `adm3` enum('ativado','desativado') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ativado',
  `adicionais` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_ultimo_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `arquivo_nome` varchar(355) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_tipo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_data_cad` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-05-03',
  `arquivo_hora_cad` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '11:11:11',
  `contaPremium` enum('ON','OFF') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ON',
  `ativado` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `membrosDados` (`id`,`login`,`senha`),
  UNIQUE KEY `loginUnico` (`login`),
  KEY `membro_indexado` (`id`,`autor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**SQL medidas**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medias` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `medias_categoria_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `medias_subcategoria_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subcat` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url2` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url3` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url4` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url5` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url6` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `autor` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `medias_indexadas` (`id`,`cat`,`subcat`,`medias_subcategoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**SQL medias_subcategoria**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medias_subcategoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `modulo` enum('media','filme','ova') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'media',
  `medias_categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `medias_subcategoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `temporada` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semana` enum('Selecionar Semana','Domingo','Segunda-Feira','Terca-Feira','Quarta-Feira','Quinta-Feira','Sexta-Feira','Sabado') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Selecionar Semana',
  `sinopse` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `status` enum('Completo','Incompleto','Andamento','Lancamento','Pausado') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Andamento',
  `produtora` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genero` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `genero_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `numeroMedias` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `autor` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `acessos` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_nome` varchar(355) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `arquivo_tipo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `arquivo_data_cad` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `arquivo_hora_cad` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nomeUnico` (`nome`),
  UNIQUE KEY `subcategoriaUnica` (`medias_subcategoria_url`),
  KEY `subcategoria_index` (`id`,`cat`,`medias_categoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**SQL medias_categoria**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medias_categoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `medias_categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `modo` enum('UNICO','MULTIPLO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNICO',
  `modulo` enum('media','filme','ova') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'media',
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `categoriaUnica` (`medias_categoria_url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nomeUnico` (`nome`),
  KEY `categoria_indexada` (`id`,`medias_categoria_url`,`modo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Explicação:** Valores postos na tabela `news` coluna `medias` são inseridos desta forma 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc esses valores são na verdade os id's da tabela `medias` coluna `id` para realizar uma comparação dentro do 2 loop esses valores são aplicados dentro do `WHERE IN`para que os itens da tabela `medias`coluna `id` com os mesmos valores apareçam dentro do segundo loop de foreach.

```
<?php 
    $newsSQL = $MYSQLI->query("
        SELECT `am1`.id,`am1`.titulo_url,`am1`.titulo,`am1`.noticia,`am1`.autor,`am1`.data,`am1`.medias,`am1`.episodios, `am2`.`arquivo_nome` as avatarImagem 
        FROM `news` as am1 FORCE INDEX (news_indexada)
        INNER JOIN `membros` as am2 FORCE INDEX (membro_indexado) ON `am1`.`autor` = `am2`.`login`
        GROUP BY `am1`.`id`,`am2`.`login`,`am1`.`autor` 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inicio, $qnt

    ");
    foreach($newsSQL as $news)
    {
        // Obs simplifiquei aqui os dados do loop no stackoverflow.com
        echo $news['titulo'];
        // Realiza a aplicação dos valores adiquiridos na tabela news coluna media com seus valores separados por virgula   
        $newsmedias1 = trim($news["medias"], ', ' );

        $media_skin = $MYSQLI->query("
            SELECT `am1`.nome,`am1`.id,`am1`.cat, `am1`.medias_categoria_url, `am1`.medias_subcategoria_url, `am1`.acessos, `am1`.ano, `am1`.numeroMedias, `am1`.status, `am1`.produtora, `am1`.genero, `am1`.arquivo_nome, `am1`.genero, `am2`.`modo` as categoriaModo , `am2`.`modulo`, COUNT(am3.id) as totalMedias
            FROM `medias_subcategoria` as am1 FORCE INDEX (subcategoria_index)
            INNER JOIN `medias_categoria` as am2 FORCE INDEX (categoria_index) ON `am1`.`cat` = `am2`.`id` 
            INNER JOIN `medias` as am3 FORCE INDEX (medias_indexadas) ON `am1`.`cat` = `am3`.`cat` AND `am1`.`id` = `am3`.`subcat` 
            WHERE am1.id IN ($newsmedias1)
            GROUP BY `am1`.`id`
            ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`am1`.`id`, '$newsmedias1') 
        ");

        foreach($media_skin as $media_dados)
        {
            // Obs simplifiquei aqui os dados do loop no stackoverflow.com
            echo $media_dados['nome'].'</br>';
        } 

    }
    // Fechamento com de conexão com o banco de dados
    $MYSQLI->close();

    // Destroi todos os valores das variaveis da News e suas Skins
    unset($newsSQL, $media_skin);   
?>
```

Comment: Isso é feito com que frequencia?

Comment: @Striffer precisa ver se você não está processando o loop desnecessariamente a todo momento. Dependendo do que você quer obter, basta realizar o loop apenas quando há alteração nos dados.

Comment: Em que momentos isso é feito? Quantas vezes por dia, em que situação, etc.

Comment: Em uma primeira tentativa, removeria o `force index` e o `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET`,  era bom normalizar a tabela e contratar uma hospedagem de boa qualidade.

Comment: pode ser uso excessivo ou desnecessário de índices.

Comment: E mesmo os INER JOIN talvez não sejam o mais adequado. Tem caso que o LEFT resolve bem (apesar de eu achar que isso vai mudar pouco o problema em questão). Pelo que você acabou de comentar, me parece mais ainda que você está reprocessando os dados desnecessariamente quando as pessoas acessam o site.

Comment: Tem outra coisa, a segunda consulta é processada para linha da primeira, ou seja tem um foreach encadeado O.o. São 5 x o retorno de linhas da segunda consulta.

Comment: @rray de fato. E tem partes similares nas duas, provavelmente compensa repensar o código todo, e simplificar a idéia. Striffer, tente explicar na pergunta qual é o resultado que você quer para a consulta. De repente compensa as pessoas ajudarem a resolver o problema principal (o resultado desejado) do que remendar o código atual.

Comment: Isso está bem mal feito, dá pra melhorar isso numa única consulta.

Comment: @Striffer, poderia explicar melhor qual é o objetivo do código/consulta. Assim alguém pode criar uma abordagem eficaz.

Answer (score 1):

Esta faltando o `fetch_assoc` no seu código, você esta tentando fazer um loop de um "resource" da query executada:

```
$newsSQL = $MYSQLI->query(...);
foreach($newsSQL as $news)
```

O correto seria isto:

```
$newsSQL = $MYSQLI->query(...);
if($result){
    while ($news = $newsSQL->fetch_assoc()){
        //...
    }
    $newsSQL->close();
}
```

outra coisa, você só pode executar outra query depois que fechar a primeira, você pode fazer um vetor pra agrupar:

```
$data = array();
$newsSQL = $MYSQLI->query(...);
if($result){
    while ($news = $newsSQL->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = array(
                    'titulo' => $news['titulo'],
                    'medias' => trim($news["medias"], ', ' )
                  );
    }
    $newsSQL->close();
}

if (empty($newmedidas) === false) {
    foreach($data as $value) {
         $media_skin = $MYSQLI->query("... ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`am1`.`id`, '" . $value['medias'] . "') ");
        echo $value['titulo'].'</br>';
        if ($media_skin) {
            while ($media_dados = $media_skin->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $media_dados['nome'].'</br>';
            }
            $media_skin->close();
        }
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Isto tudo é apenas um exemplo, você pode usar o `mysqli_result::fetch_all` ao invés de criar um vetor, outra situação é que pra maior segurança você estude mais o mysqli que é a API do php, pois é muito recomendável que se use `stmt`.

Recomendações pra você estudar:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-stmt.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php